# Responsive grid with columns of same height

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid-layout

I'm struggling with what should be a simple layout problem

I have a layout with 4 headline boxes.
The 4 boxes need to be the same height when 4 across ("deskop" view).
They also need to be the same height when 2 across ("tablet" view).
When full width ("mobile" view), the height's don't matter.

I've setup a Fiddle to show what I currently have & what happens when it responds.

https://jsfiddle.net/c5oumq2z/

The

```
<div class="report_v3_summary_box">
```

is to add a background color to the content and to add the margin when the columns respond.

Does anyone have any advice please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options in my view: CSS or JS.

With JS you can use a jquery library like [matchheight](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height).

With CSS, preferred method, you can use flexbox property to get desired effect. [Here's a really nice guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to flexbox. [Here's an example](https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard) (at the bottom).

What you basically need is (on the parent container, which is the row in your case):

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
display: flex;
```

Then, on `.report_v3_summary_box`:

```
height: 100%;
```

And move the margin bottom to the: `.col.l3.m6.s12`.

Comment: Thanks lehel - that what I needed. I've stayed away from Flexbox because of the IE11 support but in this case, it seems to work when I test.

Comment: You're welcome. Personally, I haven't had issues with flexbox and IE11, but caniuse says it's only partial support. I can imagine not all the features of flexbox are implemented (or implemented proper) but a simple thing like this, is.

https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Since we are in 2017 maybe you can use "Grid".
Here is an example how you can do this with minimum effort:

https://jsfiddle.net/herrfischerhamburg/ym2rc6tm/1/
(Resize Browserwindow, it's responsive)

Example CSS for 1 x 4 Columns:

```
.grid-container {
    grid-template-rows: 1fr; 
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
}
```

Easy?